# Reseting USB for scanner

Tags: linux, usb, sane

This is a question on:[superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/191326/linux-reseting-usb-for-scanner), since one reply suggested I ask here...

My distro does not yet have a backend for my scanner, but the last release of SANE does. So I downloaded the source and installed.

Scanning goes fairly well except that for some reason at the end of a scan I get an error message:

"reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address xx"

After that I can't scan anything until I unplug and replug the ( USB ) scanner.

Since I expect my distro to pick up the latest sane version within a few months, for now all I would like to do is reset the scanner so it can do the next page.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

PS: The kernel version is: 2.6.31-22

Comment: It might be handy to know the distro and scanner.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution but a workaround:

Some devices have a problem working with USB 2.0 and ehci_hcd.
I'm not really sure if this is a bug in the ehci_hcd code or on some other place, I just encountered it sometimes.

You could try a `modprobe -r ehci_hcd` so the USB 2.0 module will be unloaded and uhci_hcd is used.

Comment: ehci_hcd is not loaded and I can't find the module.

Comment: Sorry meant to say--ehci_hcd is not loaded and I can't find the module in with the other modules. Same goes for uhci_hcd.

Comment: so maybe its built into the kernel. which distribution are you using?

Comment: Mint the Ubuntu based version.